# Is a Collection Null

Tags: c#

```
var customers = new List<BECustomer>();
customers = GetCustomers();
```

But I don't understand why `customers[0] == null` even if 
`customers.Any()==true` or 
`customers.Count == 1` or 
`customers==null` is false

How do I check for null customers?

Comment: Do you mean Check the customers collection for being null? or any of the customers in the colleciton for being null?

Answer (score 2):

This is a difference.

You list is not null since you instantiated it with new List() and then assign getCustomers(). Maybe this is returning null.

But an element in the list can be null. For example:

```
customers[0] = null
```

Then you have set the first element in the array to null.

So to summarize:

```
if (customers == null)
```

Checks if the customerzs variable points to null

```
if (customers[0] == null)
```

Checks if the first element in the array is null

Comment: Initialization doesn't matter as it is overridden by return value from `GetCustomers`

Comment: That true. But I think the OP confuses customers[0] = null and customers == null

Comment: Actually you are not correct. The customers object is not null not because he instantiated it before, it is not null cause probably the GetCustomers() method returns a not null List. Instead of initializing the customers object with var customers = new List<BECustomer>(); he can just say List<BECustomer> customers; The other part of the explanation is correct, as customers is the container of other objects that may or may not be null.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
customers.Any(c => c == null)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check that with `customers.Contains(null)`. See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22SYSTEM.COLLECTIONS.GENERIC.LIST%601.CONTAINS%22%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22SILVERLIGHT,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if any item of a collection is null, you can use this extension method.

```
public static bool AnyNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    where T : class
{
    return items.Any(item => item == null);
}
```

Usage:

```
var customers = GetCustomers();
bool anyCustomerNull = customers.AnyNull();
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I constrained T to reference types. Nevertheless, if T would be unconstrained it would return false for value types.

Answer (score 1):

`new List<BECustomer().Add(null)` will have the same effect. Non-null, non-empty list whch contains `null` element./

Answer (score 0):

Because there is one customer, that is set to `null`.